# MSSQL Incompatibility with Organic Group Views Filter Handlers

Tags: views, organic-groups, database

I have a view which filters all the organic groups for a user. I wanted to add a Views Filter to filter by OG Role, however it is not possible.

I would very much appreciate any help. Basically any OG Role filter using a Views Filter Handler cannot be used if the database is an MSSQL database. When selecting one of the filters, it errors out and then the view has to be re-created since the view can no longer be shown within the UI. I opened a drupal issue a few months ago, but no response as of yet.

The error message is as follows:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'og_role.rid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.: `SELECT r.*, r.name AS _field_0 FROM {og_role} r GROUP BY r.name;` `Array ( )` in `og_handler_filter_user_roles->get_value_options()` (line 14 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\og\includes\views\handlers\og_handler_filter_user_roles.inc).

I'm almost postive that I have to rewrite Line 13 to support SQLSRV database types.

Line 13: `->groupBy('r.name')`

Here is the relevant code:

```
/**
 * Field handler to provide a list of OG roles of a user.
 */
class og_handler_filter_user_roles extends views_handler_filter_many_to_one {

  function get_value_options() {
    $this->value_options = array();
    // Get all role names.
    $results = db_select('og_role', 'r')
      ->fields('r')
      ->groupBy('r.name')
      ->execute();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      $this->value_options[$result->name] = $result->name;
    }
  }

  function query() {
    // Get the og_membership table from relations.
    foreach ($this->query->relationships as $alias => $info) {
      if ($info['table'] == 'og_membership') {
        // If there is a og_membership table present. Add some conditions.
        $rel = $this->relationship;
        $this->query->add_where_expression(NULL, $alias . '.gid = ' . $rel . '.gid');
        $this->query->add_where_expression(NULL, $alias . '.group_type = ' . $rel . '.group_type');
        break;
      }
    }

    parent::query();
  }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report for a module, and should be reported in module's issue queue. Reporting bugs here is forbidden, see [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok then please close the help request. I only submitted it, because I felt it was a way to also learn how to patch issues such as this for the future, but if it doesn't belong, then it no longer needs to remain open. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: if you want to learn how to patch etc, it might be OK, but, also in help center, there is a requirement to provide relevant parts of code if you are asking how to fix code. If you identified the place that causes this error, you may edit relevant part into your question, then tell us what have you tried to make it work, and expect us to answer :) That you are welcome to do, all right.

Comment: Close vote retracted, and edited it a bit to improve formatting. Good luck. Have you tried adding `->groupBy('r.rid')` just after `->groupBy('r.name')`?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. As soon as I added that, it shows that another one was missing, and then another, etc. etc. Line 13 is now:       ->groupBy('r.name')->groupBy('r.rid')->groupBy('r.gid')->groupBy('r.group_type')->groupBy('r.group_bundle'). Thank you very much. Would you like to add the answer, or should I?

Comment: As I have said long ago - if I guess in comments, it means it's just a guess, and whoever did the real work of trying and testing things should get all the rep ;) You did it, you post it :) And don't forget to post it in the issue queue as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12027/discussion-between-nwom-and-molot)

Comment: Please do NOT edit answers into a question, and avoid "chameleon" ones. If you are convinced it is not answered yet, please edit it in a way that does not look like "answer in question" issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing Line 13 to:

```
->groupBy('r.name')
->groupBy('r.rid')
->groupBy('r.gid')
->groupBy('r.group_type')
->groupBy('r.group_bundle')
```

Comment: Please try to use code syntax for code. And no need for a "thank you" in answers :) if you really feel you need, put it in comment (just don't get surprised when it's get deleted)